# Как исправить двойное подключение файлов?

Tags: vue.js

Используя `Vue UI` создал шаблонный проект, единственное — добавил `vue.config.js` и `variables.scss`. Сборка проходит как положено, но в конечный `index.html` файлы подключаются по 2 раза.

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    productionSourceMap: false,
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: `@import "~@/variables.scss";`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#preload) описано для чего это и где можно отключить:

> [`<link rel="preload">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) — это подсказки для браузера, указывающие на
>   ресурсы, которые необходимо загрузить в первую очередь. Запросы на
>   такие ресурсы будут отправлены ещё на этапе загрузки страницы, до
>   начала её рендеринга.
>
> По умолчанию приложение Vue CLI автоматически генерирует
>   preload-подсказки для всех файлов, которые необходимы при
>   первоначальном рендеринге вашего приложения.
>
> Эти подсказки внедряются [@vue/preload-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/preload-webpack-plugin) и могут быть
>   изменены / удалены с помощью `chainWebpack` через
>   `config.plugin('preload')`.